# move div to top

Tags: sass

I got window and would like to **always** show it on the **top-right** even when resizing the entire window. Currently my window works fine on the top-left, but I would like to show it on the **top right** when clicking the button, and if the user resizes the entire window always keep it on the top right corner. Does anyone know how to make this happen? Thanks in advance!

**Note:** 
- I always want the pop-up window to be draggable.

Here's a live demo: [**LIVE DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/kayicx6htoRRaE7rPicJ?p=preview)

```
display: boolean = false;
public positionLeft = 0;
public positionTop = 30;

showDialog() {
    this.display = true;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using css?

Comment: You given positionLeft = 0 in the code. Make it as positionRIght = 0.

Comment: @yurzui I tried it with some css, but still no luck, any ideas how to get it work?

Comment: @AlexisToby I tried it with positionRight but no luck

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/taTYTwpzpFGCRdxcggj4?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui your solution works, but I still want the user to drag the pop-up window, and your solution doesn't allow that.

Comment: At least you should add this to your question

Comment: @yurzui yes I just added that in my question. Thanks

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/uWQmyU83MFMUBVaT5dsw?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `float` it right to position the `dialog` and to make it draggable.

Here is the working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/N9edj1DAq32KqnWLwqj5?p=preview)